# Is switching database dynamically possible in MSSQL?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, schema

I have a scenario where we have different database for every user

```
  eg:  user1 = userDB1 (database name)
       user2 = userDB2 (database name)

       ..
       userN = userDBN
```

In my code I have a query something like this.

```
 select * from user1.product;
 select * from user2.product;
```

so i have to derive & change the db name just before firing this query.

I want to know if i can do some change at MS-SQL server side, where i have to just right query

```
select * from user.product;
```

so that user will be replaced by user1 or user2 just before start of the transaction. Is there any mechanism available db side which i can use to switch db name just before firing query.

Since there are many complex query, I have go to change each query which is lot of pain.

Note- All this DB's are there at same SQL server.

Thank you in Advance !!

Comment: Create a database User with a generic procedure that executes the correct query in the correct database for the correct user.

Comment: You could use [dynamic sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), or update the connection string in Java.  But I'd recommend you consider adding User as  [foreign key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx) to your tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could prefix dynamically every query with:

```
USE userDB1; SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are talking about databases, not schemas?

```
select * from user1.product; -- user1 is scheme
select * from user1..product; --user1 is database
```

In case of schemas you can:

1. create schema for each user
2. set default schema for database user (NOT server login). In your case it should be different for all users.
3. when you execute query

   select * from product;

table 'product' will be from default schema.

In case of databases you should try to alter connection string for each user